# Optimizing a database-driven table display

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I'm in the process of revising a PHP page that displays all of our items with various statistics regarding each one.  We're looking at a period running from the first of the month one year ago up to yesterday.  I've managed to get a basic version of the script working, but it performs poorly.  The initial implementation of this script (not my revision) retrieved all sales records and item information at once, then used the resulting records to create objects (not mysql_fetch_objects).  These were then stored in an array that used hard-coded values to access the object's attributes.  The way this is all set up is fairly confusing and doesn't easily lend itself to reusability.  It is, however, significantly faster than my implementation since it only calls to the database once or twice.

My implementation utilizes three calls.  The first obtains basic report information needed to create `DateTime` objects for the report's range (spanning the first of the month twelve months ago up to yesterday's date).  This is, however, all it's used for and I really don't think I even need to make this call.  The second retrieves all basic information for items included in the report.  This comes out to 854 records.  The last `select` statement retrieves all the sales information for these items, and last I checked, this returned over 6000 records.

What I tried to do was select only the records pertinent to the current item in the loop, represented by the following.

```
foreach($allItems as $item){
    //Display properties of item here
    //db_controller is a special class used to handle DB manipulation
    $query = "SELECT * FROM sales_records WHERE ...";
    $result = $db_controller->select($query);
    //Use sales records to calculate report values
}
```

This is the problem.  Calling to the database for each and every item is extremely time-consuming and drastically impacts performance.  What's returned is simply the sums of quantities sold in each month within the timeframe specified earlier in the script, along with the resulting sales amounts.  At maximum, each item will only have 13 sales records, ranging from 2015/1 to 2016/1 for example.  However, I'm not sure if performing a single fetch for all these sales records before the loop will help performance, the reason being that I would then have to search through the result array for the first instance of a sales record pertaining to the current item.  What can I do to alleviate this issue?  Since this is a script important to the company's operations, I want to be sure that performance on my script is just as quick as the old script or, at the very least, only slightly slower than the old script.  My results are accurate but just painfully slow.

Comment: sounds like the original program was well written (limited SQL queries, encapsulated in an OOP design). I suggest you go back to that, and try and adapt it to meet the new requirements. Beyond that, there is not enough info in your question to really help

Comment: A single `SELECT` with a `GROUP BY` should get you all the "sums" in a single query.